# The requirement of a period succeeding direct quotes

Tags: punctuation

> He raised his eyebrows. "You can't think of one, can you?" This is what happens if...

Without considering the practice of seperately paragraphing direct quotations, is this sentence correct? Is the presence of a period after '"can you?"' required, or can it be dropped in this particular case?

Should the sentence above be rephrased into something like:

> He raised his eyebrows. "You can't think of one, can you?". This is what happens if...

Comment: Double punctuation is frowned upon by many and should be used, if at all, only to clarify. Here, it's unnecessary: the question mark acceptably does 'double duty'.

Comment: I'm not sure why the third sentence ( This is what ... ) is there.